# Why we have no (or close to none) children of the forest in the north but beyond the wall

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Alright my history and geography on Westeros might be a little shaky so feel free to correct me on any presumptions

So , Westeros was  covered with the children of the forest from the north to Dorne before the First Men came .

After the first man set their foot on Westeros there was a big war between them and the children of the forest which lasted for centuries if not decades.Finally there was a truce and Westeros was split between the first man and children of the forest .

As per the truce, the children got the deep forest and the first man the rest...now we are to believe that henceforth the children dwell in the forest INCLUDING THE FOREST OF THE NORTH ..... until the Andals came in.

With the ships of the Andals landing on Westeros several years after the truce ,the Andals burned and ravaged the deep forest settlements of the children and pushed them north. Thus decimating the population of the children.

My question is if the Andals were solely responsible for desolating the children of the forest in the south and pushing them north why is it we don't find any Children of the forest in the north where they can't be hurt by the Andals and would be protected by the truce (between them and the first men)

The books however tells us that the only place the children live now(found at) is beyond the wall(at least for sure ),

I understand and accept the children of the forest being driven to extinction anywhere but the north .

Well I know that truces can be forgotten and the first men could start killing the children again but I highly doubt this as the north is big and thus the first men should not  have any reason NOT to share it the children and breaking the truce(considering they remenber and hold honor high).Also they now share the same religion as the children so cultural hatred would be dampened as well.

And even in  the case of  north-men  eradicating the remaining children in the north why is there no mention of this in history as by this time the Maesters were a thing in Westeros.

Comment: There is no concrete evidence that the children do not live in the north. After all, the Ghost of High Heart is probably a child of the forest, or has some of their blood in her, and she lives south of the Neck.

Comment: if they do ,they are not many ,and also why are they in hidding

Answer (score 3):

I have a few theories, and please forgive me, I think you are probably far more knowledgeable about this than I am, and I wouldn't necessary count this as an answer but I can't comment yet so here goes:

Theory #1: could their diminished population be due to the cutting down of the weirwood trees? I know their powers are connected and a lot of the weirwoods were cut down. But there are still some in the North so that doesn't entirely answer your question...but perhaps the demonstrated hostility towards the weirwoods speaks to your thoughts that perhaps the CotF were killed off/scared away.

Theory #2: there seems to be a lot of support for the theory that The Wall is a sort of magical dividing line. We know that it has magical protections, and perhaps those prevent CotF from moving from one side of the wall to the other. Or perhaps the CotF just want/need to be on the "magical" side of the wall with their various magical brethren.

Theory #3: it appears that since around the time of the comet/Dany's dragons that magic has been becoming more powerful/pronounced/awakened/what have you perhaps the CotF population was diminished or incapacitated during these less magical times (like dragons) and they are only recently starting to re-emerge...
Or perhaps it is facets of all 3 of my theories  (or none!)

Most likely I feel like perhaps my theories are smaller parts of a larger argument to be made by one more knowledgeable than myself! 
Hope that was at least a little helpful? :)

Comment: I did not like your third theory. CotF seems to have their own magic, just like the white walkers. It should not be connected to the existence of dragons. There is absolutely nothing that supports this theory in the books. CotF talked to Bran and Meera, they talked about their battle with the First Men and their agreement but never this. The first and second theories are logical. I believe the answer is a combination of these two.