# Do Children of the Forest exist in Westeros in the time which is current for the series and the books?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Are there any Children of the Forest in Westeros in the time which is current for the series and the books??

> except those who lived with Bloodraven under the tree?

I'm interested in both series and book answers

> because it seems to me that series and books don't deviate in that question

Comment: Related, mayhaps dupe? http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/127890/why-we-have-no-or-close-to-none-children-of-the-forest-in-the-north-but-beyond

Answer (score 9):

It is a common theory (even in-universe) that the [Ghost of High Heart](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Ghost_of_High_Heart) is actually one of the children of the forest.

From the linked wiki:

> While most people believed the woods witch to be a dwarf, her friend, Jenny of Oldstones, claimed she was one of the children of the forest.

Which brings us to another point, [Jenny of Oldstones](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jenny_of_Oldstones) was friends with this particular woods witch. Jenny was the wife of [Duncan Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Duncan_Targaryen), and while we don't know when she was born, we do know that the Prince of Dragonflies was born in the early 220s. Even if the witch was born around the same time, that would put her around 70-80 years old, which is *very old* for someone that lives alone in the wilderness(at least for a human).

There is plenty of evidence that this is the same woods witch that Jenny was friends with. The biggest and most obvious is that all she asks for her prophecies is some wine and a song: [Jenny's Song](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jenny%27s_song). Most people believe that the Jenny in the song is the same Jenny of Oldstones. IIRC when Tom was singing it to her, there were tears streaming down her cheeks. Also she says this to Arya:

> I gorged on grief at Summerhall, I need none of yours.

Summerhall being where Jenny and Duncan Targaryen died.

Then there's this line from Thoros that brings it all back around:

> ... she has her own ways of knowing things, that one. The weirwoods whisper in her ear when she sleeps.

Which matches how we've seen other children of the forest get their information about the past, the future, and distant events.  All signs point to her being a lonely child of the forest.

Comment: But Children of the Forest have a specific appearance, which differs a lot from people's appearance. Is it so difficult to distinguish them?

Comment: @Schullz I would say yes, because nobody has actually seen one (save Bran's party) to compare against. Couple that with the fact that most people south of the neck barely even care that they existed in the first place, and now all you have is an old dwarf woman that's spent way too much time in the sun. There's no real reason for anyone to think she's a CoF, they've been extinct for 6,000 years.

Answer (score 2):

The [Andal Invasion](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Andal_invasion) was the last time [Children of the Forest](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Children_of_the_Forest) were seen in Westeros 6,000 years ago. The battle decimated their already small numbers as [explained](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Children_of_the_Forest) in GoT Wiki.

> There were simply never that many of her race in the first place, even before the First Men arrived. They only sparsely inhabited Westeros, and they took severe losses against the White Walkers from which they never really recovered. When the Andals came they killed the few Children they encountered, and the survivors secretly fled beyond the Wall, where none would follow.

Thousands of years after the battle in present day Westeros, Children of the Forest have become mythological legends. In Season 2, Maester Luwin tells Bran that people think they never existed at all. While one could argue there "could" be children hiding out in Westeros at present time, the likelihood is extremely unlikely. Aside from mere speculation, it is safe to deduce that the answer is to your question is no. Any surviving Children of the Forest are north of the wall.

Comment: Where is that quote from?

Comment: "Any surviving Children of the Forest are north of the wall" - but Westeros is the whole continent, to the South and to the North from the Wall

Comment: @Todd Edited source.